# IE8: Access denied

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to access and API using jquery/post but its not working in IE8. Its throwing Access denied error in IE8 only.

js code:

```
var url = 'http://somecomp.cartodb.com:80/api/v1/map?map_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&stat_tag=API';
    var data = //some long data of length greater than 3000
    $.ajax({
        crossOrigin: !0,
        type: "POST",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(a) {
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function(a) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    })
```

If I add ?callback=? at the end of url, it still fires the error callback but with statusText: 'success' and code: 200

here is full code: http://textuploader.com/ato0w

Comment: Can you try to change `dataType` to `jsonp`?

Comment: No, but I think jsonp is only for GET request... in success I am getting error

Answer (score -1):

Change `dataType` to `jsonp` will allow you to make cross-domiain requests. This will work only with `GET` requests.

If you're using CORS for accessing cross-origin resource, try to add the following line:

```
$.ajax({
     crossDomain: true, // replace "crossOrigin: !0;"
});
```

If this not working for you, try to add the following line above `$.ajax()` call.

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

Comment: oh! I need to send a post request as the data object is quite large.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Could you check the updated answer?

Comment: What's your version of `jQuery`?

Comment: I have added the full code, link: http://textuploader.com/ato0w. Please check now. Using jquery version 1.7.2

Comment: `!0` is `true` so changing to be explicitly `true` shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: **Never** assign a value to `jQuery.support.cors` — That's used by jQuery internally to detect CORS support in the browser. Changing it is only going to break things.

Comment: @Quentin, I said to replace it, because I think there's no `crossOrigin`, `crossDomain` is the mentioned in documentation.

Comment: Setting `crossDomain` explicitly is also pointless almost all of the time. It only matters when you are making a *same* origin request that gets an HTTP redirect to a different origin.